# "could not open connection" behat and selenium

Tags: firefox, selenium, behat

I have a problème and really don't know where it comes from. I'm using behat, selenium and goutte to do tests.

My behat.yml :

```
    default:
  paths:
    features: features
    bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/bootstrap
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      goutte: ~
      selenium2: ~
```

I have a simple scenario :

```
  @javascript
  Scenario: Searching for "test"
    Given I go to "https://www.google.fr"
    When I fill in "q" with "test"
    And I press "btnG"
    Then I should see "speedtest"
```

When I run it, my firefox browser is opening, but nothing happen. Here is the result :

```
  @javascript
  Scenario: Searching for "test"          # features/test.feature:7
    Given I go to "https://www.google.fr" # FeatureContext::visit()
      Could not open connection
    When I fill in "q" with "test"        # FeatureContext::fillField()
    And I press "btnG"                    # FeatureContext::pressButton()
    Then I should see "speedtest"
```

It's weird because when i remove the "javascript", everything run normally. So I think my problem comes from firefox. Moreover, the firefox browser which is opened is not the "normal" browser (the characteres are smallers).

Can you help me please ? :)

Comment: I've just found that firefox 32 + selenium 2.38 don't play together but updating to selenium 2.43 and all is well.

Answer (score 1):

I had weird problems with Firefox and swithed to Chrome which solved my problems. You need to download [Chrome driver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html).

**behat.yml**

```
default:
    context:
        class: 'FeatureContext'
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
            mink_driver: true
            kernel:
                env: test
                debug: true
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: 'http://localhost/local/sport/web/app_test.php/'
            browser_name: 'chrome'
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
    paths:
        features: 'src/Football/TeamBundle/Features'
        bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/Context
```

**I'm usign these packages:**

```
"require-dev": {
    "behat/behat": "2.5.*@stable",
    "behat/behat-bundle": "1.0.0",
    "behat/symfony2-extension": "1.1.2",
    "behat/mink": "1.5.0",
    "behat/mink-extension": "~1.3",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "1.1.1",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "1.0.9",
    "phing/phing": "2.8.2"
},
```

**Working Feature:**

```
Feature: I say hello

@javascript
Scenario: I say hello here
When I go to '/'
Then I fill in "text_hello" with "Hello"
```